# Eager instantiation of Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I have a Singleton

```
public class Singleton
{
     private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

     private Singleton()
     {
         System.out.println("Instance created.");
     }

     public static Singleton getInstance()
     {
         return instance;
     }
}
```

I can run this code, but the instance is not being created unless `getInstance()` gets called. This is weird, as my `println()` in the constructor should execute since I am using eager instantiation.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Well, you need a way to execute that constructor first. Which is with `getInstance`

Comment: The class is not initialized until the "first (mumble) reference".  Simply loading the class does not initialize it, but (among other things) invoking a static method of the class does.

Comment: This states very clearly what causes class initialization: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instance will not get created until the class will get loaded for the first time, if you want eager initialization without invoking `getInstance()` method you can call

```
Class.forName(Singleton.class.getName());
```

on initialization

you have instance as static field, and static field gets initialized on class load event, so if you want eager initialization you just load class eagerly

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: So in essence the instance won't be created until it is needed? Somewhat like lazy instantiation huh? Unless I use `Class.forName(Singleton.class);`

Comment: @JigarJoshi are you sure this compiles? i think it should be `Class.forName(Singleton.class.getName());`

Comment: Correction: Static init does not occur when the class is loaded.  Static init occurs on the first "significant" reference to the class -- invoke a static, create an instance, and 2-3 other things.

Comment: @Hot that is internally loading class

Comment: That is [initializing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) the class, which is different from loading.  A class may be loaded (eg, to resolve a method reference that is never called) and then never initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Once the class is accessed somewhere in the code, all the static variables associated with it are loaded and assigned their values.

If the first point in your program where the class is used is the point where you call `getInstance()`, then the class will be loaded there, the static variable will be initialized, and the constructor will be run.